# Selling property abroad and transferring the money in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, european-union, property-taxes, greece

I am a UK citizen and there is a property in Greece that my family wants to sell. It is an old property which I (and three more family members) inherited and paid taxes normally. The facts:

- The property was first acquired in 1973
- I have a percentage of the property which increased due to family members passing away
- I intent to transfer the money in the UK in order to buy a house
- You do not pay taxes for selling a property in Greece

I have read that generally, when you sell property you have to pay capital gains. However, I am not sure if this is the case here because it is not a property of which I had any income and it is abroad. On the contrary, we had lost a lot of money for the taxes and repairs in Greece.

Does it still need to be taxed via a self assessment or not? And what calculation will apply?

Comment: When did you first inherit a share?

Comment: Is this really important? My uncle passed away in 2003 and my father, me and my sister inherited an amount. My father died in 2013 and we inherited the rest of it. We paid inheritance tax in any occasion.

Comment: Just trying to get a general sense - it might affect the way capital gains operates as there have been some changes over the years. The dates will also matter to you for calculating any gain as (I think) the basis is the value at the time you inherit.